# Get a variable from an ArrayList that uses external class

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` called `results` that uses the class `ItemObjects` when I want to add an item in `results`. My problem is that I cannot manage to retrieve a specific String from an item.

The class code is:

```
public class ItemObjects {
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;


    public ItemObjects(String text1, String text2){
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
    }

    public String getmText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public void setmText1(String mText1) {
        this.mText1 = mText1;
    }

    public String getmText2() {
        return mText2;
    }

    public void setmText2(String mText2) {
        this.mText2 = mText2;
    }
}
```

And I use the following code to add an item into the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList results = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
//THis part goes inside a for using i as increment;
ItemObjects obj = new ItemObjects(type, sender);
results.add(i , obj);
```

I have tried several things to retrieve the data such as:

```
String type =  ItemObjects.getmText1();
```

or:

```
String type= results.get(i);
```

the first try, only retrieves the mText1 from the first item, and the second is an object and I dn't know how i should get the mText1 from it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding the Value

```
ArrayList<ItemObjects> results = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
ItemObjects obj = new ItemObjects(type, sender);
results.add(obj);
```

For getting the Value

```
for (int i=0, i<result.size(); i++)
{
    String type =  results.get(i).mText1;
    String sender=  results.get(i).mText2; 

    Toast.makeText(this, "" + type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + sender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ArrayList results = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<ItemObjects> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then `results.get()` will return `ItemObjects`.

Or you can simply cast your current `result.get()` to `ItemObjects`